# Using headObject to get x-amz-meta from S3 File

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata, bucket

I have a file on S3 with some metadata for example
x-amz-meta-description="some description"
This metadata was included when I uploaded the file to S3.
If I use Amazon console to check the metadata, the metadata is there.
Next, I added the following to the CORS configuration to have access to the headers:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

From my web app, I'm trying to check the headers of my file. I'm using the following javascript code:

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'XXX', secretAccessKey: 'YYY'})
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'zzz'}});
var params = {Bucket: 'zzz',Key: 'content/myfile.doc'};
bucket.headObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    else
        console.log(data);
});
```

After running the code data.Metadata is empty.
Is there any other configuration to get the metadata associated to the file? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for all

PS:I used getObject function, but Metadata is still empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expose custom headers like this:

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-description</ExposeHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Adding ExposeHeader helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: I know this might be a given, but it took me a minute to get that the description part of `x-amz-meta-description` is the key.  You need to replace 'description' with whatever key name you want to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is still a defect with the metadata and the fix provided at this link isn't working: `2017-05-07T03:34:17.319Z`.

Allowing the headers Made in CORS fixed the headers showing in the HTTP request, but not in the callback. I ended up hashing the object myself.